# Sharepoint API iOS

Tags: ios, json, sharepoint

I'm trying to connect to a Sharepoint API service and post some data

```
let params = ["__metadata": ["type": "SP.Data.TaxiListItem"], "Title": "Some Title", "From": "WORK", "To": "HOME", "SpUrl": ["__metadata": 
    ["type": "SP.FieldUrlValue"], "Url": "http://sps", "Description": "Site Desc"]] as [String : Any]

Alamofire.request("http://sps/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Taxi')/Items",
    method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, 
    headers: ["X-RequestDigest": formDigest, "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-Type": 
    "application/json;odata=verbose"]).responseJSON {

    // response
}
```

But the response's statusCode is **400** with the following error:

> Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

it's seems that the authentication token is wrong or with a bad format.
It's your parmateter **formDigest** in the http header of your request.
This token is needed by SharePoint to know who is calling him. Without it you are not authenticate to SharePoint and so you will have an error code 400

Comment: I fill the **formDigest** by first sending a request to ***http://sps/_api/contextInfo***

Comment: you first get your form digest and after call your API, that seems to be right.  Have a look at this : [Development of iPhone client application for SharePoint 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571996/Development-of-iPhone-client-application-for-Share). Or this link : [helper library to simplify authentication and querying of Microsoft SharePoint](https://github.com/jimmywim/SPMobile) I'm not dev on IOS, hop this links can help you